# Python, numpy correlation returns nan

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get the correlation between two matrices from the boston dataset. So I'm doing this.

```
import sklearn as skl
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


boston_dataset = load_boston()
X = boston_dataset.data
Y = boston_dataset.target

# Correlation between RM and Y
RM = X[:, 5:6]
np.corrcoef(RM, Y.reshape((506,1)))
```

But I got NAN in every value of the matrix.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2526: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  c = cov(x, y, rowvar)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2455: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  c *= np.true_divide(1, fact)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2455: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  c *= np.true_divide(1, fact)
array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       ...,
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]])
```

What's happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find correlation of single values, which the warning says, has 0 degree of freedom (for correlation between two single values) and hence divide by 0 results in nan, which is expected. Maybe you meant to find correlation of columns instead of rows, like this:

```
np.corrcoef(RM, Y.reshape((506,1)), rowvar=False)
```

output:

```
[[1.         0.69535995]
 [0.69535995 1.        ]]
```

**Explanation**: By default, numpy `np.corrcoef` takes row-wise correlation of the two matrices. According to [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html), if you want column-wise correlation, you can use `rowvar` arguement:

*If rowvar is True (default), then each row represents a variable, with observations in the columns. Otherwise, the relationship is transposed: each column represents a variable, while the rows contain observations.*

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was looking for, what is rowvar for? I'm still a little lost about why my code didn't work. (I'm sorry, I'm new in this, also I know my english isn't good either, so sorry for that as well)

Comment: @Sharki No worries. Your english is good and the question is clear. I added some explanation to the post about `rowvar`.

Comment: Sorry once again, when you say `row wise` you mean for example: `np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]])` and when we're talking about `columns wise` it means `np.array( [[1], [2], [3]])`?

Comment: @Sharki correct. Be mindful, you still can input `np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]])` and try to get column-wise correlation and the result would be `nan` (same with row-wise for `np.array( [[1], [2], [3]])`). If you input a 2-D matrix, be mindful of which correlation you are trying to get (column vs. row).

Answer (score 1):

Try slicing your X array on a single index (so `X[:, 5]` instead of `X[:, 5:6]`). Then it will be the same shape as your Y array, without needing to reshape it. The following works:

```
# Correlation between RM and Y
RM = X[:, 5]
np.corrcoef(RM, Y)
```

Comment: `np.corrcoef` can get 2-D arrays as inputs and besides that, the OP's input to it is in fact two 2-D arrays.